# Is there a security problem runing chrome headleass without sandbox on a server

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm using `caputer-website` which internally uses `puppeteer` to take a
 screenshoot of a website on my `nodejs` server, in order to compose a pdf file with it. The problem is that I need to run the browser without
 `sandbox` which I think can lead to security issues on the server, if this is right what I'm exposed to and how can I
 mitigate the problems?

Maybe, also important is the server configuration `NodeJS` server
 running on `heroku` which exposes an api to make this pdf. Internally
 the `NodeJS` server takes this screenshot using `capture-website` and
 appends it to the pdf file than sends the stream to the client for
 download.

Comment: I think there isn't any known vulnerability. But this doesn't mean that they can't appear in the future

Comment: Ok thanks for help I will leave this here for anyone who is looking into this as well

Comment: I think there were some security notes related to puppeteer, I'll take some look. "Chromium itself operates under assumption that the renderer process is compromised."

Comment: Right now your are asking for a library recommendation that is able to use the sandbox, I guess? You might want to rephrase your question as asking for a software library recommendation is considered off-topic for stackoverflow.